# How to check conditional in CSS?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, css, masterslider

I have a problem when using Master Slider.

It auto generates a lot of classes.

In my case, I load video and picture into the slide.

In the code I check with:

```
<?php if($item->type == 1): ?>   <!-- is Video -->
    <img class="ms-thumb video_slider" ... />
?>
<?php if($item->type == 2): ?>   <!-- is Picture -->
    <img class="ms-thumb picture_slider" ... />
    <div class="picturediv"></div> <!-- I tried to add manual element like that to assign instead of using: `ms-thumb-ol` but it auto remove when slide is generate -->
?>
```

It will be generated structure like this:

```
            div.ms-thumb-frame
                div.ms-thumb video_slider 
                div.ms-thumb-ol

            div.ms-thumb-frame
                div.ms-thumb picture_slider 
                div.ms-thumb-ol
```

I want to add a button play into that with code:

```
div.ms-thumb-frame {
    position: relative;
}
div.ms-thumb-frame div.ms-thumb-ol {
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage2.png);
    height: 55px;
    width: 57px;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin:auto;
}
div.ms-thumb-frame div.ms-thumb-ol:hover {
    background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage-11.png);
}
```

You can see, I style only element `ms-thumb-ol`.

This element is same in another element.

Is there any method to check in `div.ms-thumb picture_slider` and `div.ms-thumb-ol` concurrent

Comment: You can make use of Sass if you want to apply conditions in css.

Comment: You mean using JavaScript or CSS or PHP? *"div.ms-thumb picture_slider and div.ms-thumb-ol concurrent"* you mean you want to check when ..ol comes after ..slider?

Comment: This can be done with CSS alone using the sibling `+` combinator. Check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to edit the `ms-thumb-ol` only, you can use the css sibling combinator, since it is next to `div.ms-thumb picture_slider`. So, to modify it, add this selector for your css:

```
div.ms-thumb picture_slider + ms-thumb-ol{
//Whatever code you want that specific button to have but not the other button
}
```

What the `+` combinator does is that it checks if the `div.ms-thumb picture_slider` class is followed by `ms-thumb-ol`. If it is, then apply styling.

**Edit:**

To make it simpler, change your code from what you have, to:

```
div.ms-thumb-frame + div.ms-thumb-ol {
position: absolute;
display: block;
background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-button-crm-homepage2.png);
height: 55px;
width: 57px;
top: 0;
left:0;
right:0;
bottom:0;
margin:auto;
}


div.ms-thumb-frame + div.ms-thumb-ol:hover {
background: url(http://www.workbooks.com/sites/default/files/image/play-    button-crm-homepage-11.png);
}
```

As long as your HTML is set up the way you showed in your question, it will work.

**Notice the only difference is the sibling combinator `+`.**

Comment: I was using operator `+` but I don't know only apply the style to `ms-thumb-ol`. You mention `you can use the css sibling selector`. You can share example? Thanks.

Comment: The code is in my answer @vanloc. The combinator* (not selector, will fix the typo) is the + sign. Use as I put it in my answer and it should work for you (as long as your html is as you put it in your question).

Comment: Thanks @Obed Marquez Parlapiano.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to style only `div.ms-thumb-ol` that comes right after `div.ms-thumb.picture_slider` element inside `div.ms-thumb-frame` you can use [CSS Adjacent sibling combinator](https://css-tricks.com/child-and-sibling-selectors/#article-header-id-1) like that:

```
div.ms-thumb-frame div.ms-thumb.picture_slider + div.ms-thumb-ol {
    /* ... */
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only two types of items...use ternary operator like this

```
$class= ($item->type == 1)?'ms-thumb video_slider':'ms-thumb picture_slider';
```

And use `$class` in `img` tag as below..

```
<img class="<?php echo $class;?>" ... />
```

Comment: Your comment only cleans my code. That's not resolve my problem.